# Android: Proguard not obfuscating code, throwing errors

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Here is my configuration:

**project.properties**:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:22
android.library=false
android.library.reference.1=../../libs/facebook/facebook-android-sdk-4.2.0/facebook
```

**proguard-project.txt**: This is empty file i.e everything is commented in it.

The project normally compiles correctly, there are no errors.

When i try to export the apk i see many errors in console (and export fails):

```
    Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    Warning: com.facebook.applinks.FacebookAppLinkResolver: can't find superclass or interface bolts.AppLinkResolver
    Warning: com.facebook.applinks.FacebookAppLinkResolver$1: can't find superclass or interface bolts.Continuation
    Warning: org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap$2: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer
    Warning: org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap$3: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer
...
```

But, if i comment out the proguard.config=... line in project.properties, i am able to export successfully without any errors - but the code is not obfuscated.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208784/proguard-returned-with-error-code-1-see-console

Comment: Kay> Yes, even though warnings get suppressed and export succeeds, but the APK itself does not work - i see ClassNotFoundExceptions when the application launches on android device.

Comment: And with minifyenabled false it runs normally?

Comment: Kay> I unzipped the exported apk, i don't see any of the jars that are part of the build classpath/export configuration - the jars are not getting included - at least i don't see them although obfuscation of my code is happening. I have not used minifyenabled false anywhere (i do not use gradle)

Comment: I am guessing for some reason, progaurd is removing them while building dex file. Turn off progaurd and it should work. But that would decrease security and increase size. Try including these classes in your package directly

Comment: It appears that the classes in the support jars too were getting obfuscated causing problem at runtime. So i had to add these: -keep class whateverpackage.** { *; } to prevent that - and only then apk would work. If there is a better way would be happy to hear about it.

Comment: hmm that makes sense. in Gradle based projects I usually turn off minifyenabled for dependency packages and turn on only for my main app package. Maybe this could help you too!

Comment: So i guess..there no way in proguard-project.properties to specify obfuscate only this package, instead of saying don't obfuscate this, this and this package via -keep.

Comment: Yes will have to tell progaurd to not obfuscate certain jars

Answer (score 0):

When you see warnings while exporting, make sure that all support libraries are available in build path.
You can further suppress some warnings and get away with that - see below.

My support jars were getting obfuscated too (not sure if this is normal) resulting in app failing at runtime, so i had to explicitly prevent their obfuscation - see below.

**project.properties**

```
proguard.config=/myapp/proguard-project.txt
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:22
android.library=false
android.library.reference.1=../../pathToLibrary
```

**proguard-project.properties**

```
#To prevent a warning message:
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**

#To prevent supporting jars from getting obfuscated you would need something like:
-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class android.** { *; }
```