# android -Progaurd return error 1

Tags: android

I want to use proguard for my application , I'm using eclipse . This is the config file :

```
-dontwarn com.parse.**

-keep class com.facebook.** {
*;
}


-keepattributes Signature

#When not preverifing in a case-insensitive filing system, such as Windows. This tool will unpack your processed jars,(if using windows you should then use):
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames

#Specifies not to ignore non-public library classes. As of version 4.5, this is the default setting
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).    
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

-dontwarn android.support.**

#Specifies to write out some more information during processing. If the program terminates with an exception, this option will print out the entire stack trace, instead of just the exception message.
-verbose

#The -optimizations option disables some arithmetic simplifications that Dalvik 1.0 and 1.5 can't handle. Note that the Dalvik VM also can't handle aggressive overloading (of static fields).
#To understand or change this check http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/optimizations.html
#-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

#To repackage classes on a single package
#-repackageclasses ''

#Uncomment if using annotations to keep them.
#-keepattributes *Annotation*

#Keep classes that are referenced on the AndroidManifest
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
#Compatibility library 
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment

#To maintain custom components names that are used on layouts XML.
#Uncomment if having any problem with the approach below
#-keep public class custom.components.package.and.name.**

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
 -keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
  void set*(***);
  *** get*();
}

#To remove debug logs:
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** w(...);
}

#To avoid changing names of methods invoked on layout's onClick.
# Uncomment and add specific method names if using onClick on layouts
#-keepclassmembers class * {
# public void onClickButton(android.view.View);
#}

#Maintain java native methods 
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}


#To maintain custom components names that are used on layouts XML:
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

#Maintain enums
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

#To keep parcelable classes (to serialize - deserialize objects to sent through Intents)
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

#Keep the R
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

When I export the application and build the apk file ,it gives me the "Progaurd return error 1" and the in the consul it returns these errors  :

```
     Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Request$Callback
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionDefaultAudience
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.FacebookError
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.FacebookError
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request$Callback
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.FacebookRequestError
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.model.GraphObject
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request$Callback
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.FacebookRequestError
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.model.GraphObject
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
 Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
 Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
 Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
 Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
 Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
 Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
 Warning: there were 82 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
 java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

There are some external libraries that I use in my application , I just need the progaurd for obfuscation

Could you help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: This question should be deleted as it has been reposted and superseded by the owner with clearer requirement in https://stackoverflow.com/q/32493248/. There is no added value in keeping the two questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android -progaurd keeps erroring with parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493248/android-progaurd-keeps-erroring-with-parse)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proguard returned with error code 1. See console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208784/proguard-returned-with-error-code-1-see-console)

Answer (score -1):

Replace
`-keep class com.facebook.** {
*;
}`

with,

```
-dontwarn com.facebook.**
```

Comment: I already tried this , it doesn't shows the error and export the app but the exported app will not be install