# android -progaurd keeps erroring with parse

Tags: android

This is my proguard rules :

```
    -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

i've searched and used lots of codes but none of them worked . these are the errors I got :

```
    Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Request$Callback
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionDefaultAudience
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.FacebookError
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.FacebookError
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request$Callback
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.FacebookRequestError
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.model.GraphObject
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request$Callback
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.FacebookRequestError
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.model.GraphObject
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
```

**please do not tell me to use dontwarn  ,yes it manage to build the app but the app will not be run**

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this

```
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
```

i.e. `**` instead of `*`

and maybe this too

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Comment: have you tested without proguard?

Comment: yes if I don't use proGuard it works fine and run without any exception

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below in your progaurd file :

```
#Parse
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
```

Hope It will help.!!

Comment: @ navidjons : try to add this : #Facebook
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature